# cannot delete files / folders in mounted drives

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount

I have dual booted Windows 10 with Ubuntu on it

Ubuntu is on a second hdd

partition table:

```
/root /dev/sdb2 30gb
/home /dev/sdb3 300gb
/swap /dev/sdb4 8gb
ntfs drive /dev/sdb5 remaining
```

but I am not able to delete files on the NTFS volume with default account, can delete with root permissions.

nor can I delete files on the Windows partitions.

I have these permissions (`ls -l`) => -rwxrwxrwx  drwxrwxrwx

What should I do?

Comment: have you tried by `nautilus`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out problem :

I had Fast-boot enabled by default in the BIOS/UEFI menu as i am Dual-Booting with Windows and Ubuntu.

In this linux detected all NTFS volumes as Hibernated once.

You can check it by   `sudo mount -a` , it will tell in last line about windows hibernation !

Windows saves the fastboot information when we Shutdown (so that it can retrive files for it) , but it does not save when Restarted !!

So Basically  **Disabling Fastboot** did the job !